# KendoUI Tabstrip open a tab based on url

Tags: kendo-ui

Is there some built in functionality to open a tab pages(kendoUI TabStrip) based on the url? or do I have to write some custom function to read the url and do some work based on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would have to parse the URL, then call the [activateTab()](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/tabstrip#activatetab) function on the tab strip to open the tab you want.

Comment: I will try this when I get back to work and let you know if it works.

Comment: You can get the ID of the tab and set that to either active or write a function that changes the display if you want to hide/show. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is what you are looking for:

HTML:

```
<div id="tabstrip">
    <ul>
        <li class="k-state-active">Page 1</li>
        <li>Page 2</li>
        <li>Page 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
        contentUrls:[
            "page1.html",
            "page2.html",
            "page3.html"
        ]
    });
});
```

It creates a 3 tabs `kendoTabStrip` and the content of each of the tabs is `page1.html`, `page2.html` and `page3.html`.

Comment: Actually what im looking to do is open the tab dynamically based on the url. For example if i sent an email and the link said page2 then in the url it would be some like www.example.com?page2. When it was processed it would automatically open the tab that corresponds with page2.

Comment: Hi @OnaBai, for this solution, how to bind angular controller? I tried to bind controller in each html files, but no luck, the binding doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution if you want to set the active tab in the rendering state (not with Js at the page load)

if you use a templete system (like groovy for play framework 1.x) you can write something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="#{if params.get('ref') == 'application'}k-state-active#{/if}">Application</li>
  <li class="#{if params.get('ref') == 'payment'}k-state-active#{/if}">Payment</li>
</ul>
<div>
  content for tab application
</div>
<div>
  content for tab payment
</div>
```

**Note:** params.get('ref') means the requests's get param with the name: 'ref'

And if you open this page with the url:
someting.dev/dashboard?ref=payment

you will get the payment tab as the active